# Is there a way to test multiple rush packages locally without publishing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, rush

I have three react projects A, B and C. Each project uses Rushjs for building and publishing packages. Project A depends on B and Project B depends on Project C. I made some changes in C. After building C, I used `rush publish` similar to `npm pack` to convert the package into .tar.gz file.

After that, added the path in the package.json of Project B -

```
dependencies : {
  "C-project": "file:D:/tar/C.tgz"
}
```

Project B is built successfully and working as expected. I'm able to access all the methods exported from Project C. Now I did the same for Project B. Ran rush publish -> Convert into .tar.gz -> Updated the package.json of Project A with -

```
dependencies : {
  "B-project": "file:D:/tar/B.tgz"
}
```

But now, building Project A throws an errors such as "XYZ" method does not exists in Project C, even though I'm able to access the methods in Project B.

Is this the correct way of testing multiple packages locally. If not, do suggest a better way of testing such scenarios without publishing them to npm registry.